# Postgres INSERT causing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, unhandled-promise-rejection

I'm running the following code

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const credentials = {
    user: "username",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "data",
    password: "password",
    port: 5432,
  };

async function appendDb(val1, val2, val3) {
  try {
    const client = new Client(credentials);
    await client.connect();
    var a = await client.query(`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (${val1}, ${val2}, ${val3})`);
    await client.end();
    return;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

appendDb('test', 'test', 'test');
```

and getting the following error

```
(node:17372) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.con.once (/usr/local/urr/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:254:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/urr/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:78:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:600:12)
(node:17372) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17372) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Not sure why this is happening since I am using catch? The following script works fine

```
  async function clientDemo() {
    try {
        const client = new Client(credentials);
        console.log(client);
        await client.connect();
        const now = await client.query("SELECT NOW()");
        await client.end();
        return now;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

  (async () => {
    const clientResult = await clientDemo();
    console.log("Time with client: " + clientResult.rows[0]["now"]);
  })();
```

so I don't think it has anything to do with being unable to connect to Postgres or invalid credentials or anything like that.

Comment: Shouldn't (${val1}, ${val2}, ${val3}\`); be (${val1}, ${val2}, ${val3})\`);   Missing ) in there?

Comment: my bad, messed up while copying my code over. doesn't fix the issue tho :(

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the database in this way.

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const credentials = {
    user: "username",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "data",
    password: "password",
    port: 5432,
  };

async function appendDb(val1, val2, val3) {
  try {
    const client = new Client(credentials);
    await client.connect();
    var a = await client.query('INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', [val1, val2, val3]);
    await client.end();
    return;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

(async () => {
    await appendDb('test', 'test', 'test');
 })();
```

Comment: Tried it, got rid of the error but still doesn't add to the database. Added console.log statements and doesn't seem like it's entering the function at all now.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have missed await in function calling. Here appendDb is an async function so it will return a promise. So, we need to wait till the promise resolves. I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Tried that as well, that causes `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know it is working now or not.